# Getting Maximum call stack size exceeded error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack

I am new to Node.js and i am developing a simple chat app using **Socket.IO**.
I made an **index.js** file and an **index.html** file.

My **index.js** files looks like this

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var util = require('util');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
     console.log('message: ' + msg);
   });
   var txt = process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
     process.tick()
     return util.inspect(text)
   });
  socket.emit('chat message',txt);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

My index.html file looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to take value from the console and print it on the browser and vice versa. In this app the chat is between the client and the server.

When i run the **index.js** file i get this on the terminal

```
listening on *:3000
```

All is fine until i hit the server with **localhost:3000** from my browser and then i get this on the terminal

```
buffer.js:0
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { // Copyright Joy
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How can i solve this? I want to get the value from the console(server) and send it to the browser(client).

**Update 1**

I get this error

```
process.tick()
             ^
TypeError: Object #<process> has no method 'tick'
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/home/sunil/Downloads/TPL/chat/index.js:16:14)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TTY.onread (net.js:526:21)
```

**Update 2** 
**process.tick()** was replaced by **process.nextTick()**
and then i get this error

```
node.js:415
            callback();
            ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. The error is generated
>   by infinite loop somewhere in your app.  Updated code inside
>   io.on('connection' ...

```
var txt = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
     process.nextTick();
     txt = util.inspect(text);
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
         console.log('message: ' + msg);

         socket.emit('chat message',txt);
       });
    });
```

> Putting socket.emit inside io.on('connection', function(socket){});
>   directly will be continuously emitting that socket event' like a infinite
>   loop and raises stack size range error. So, Please update your code as
>   above.

Comment: I updated the code with your code and I got the message from client to server but with this in addition to message - **Missing error handler on `socket`. undefined** - I understood that i need to do error handling. Another thing that i am still not able to send message from server to client. When i type the message on server and hit enter, i get this the error.. see the updated question for the error.

Comment: Ok another update. The function **process.tick()** is wrong and the correct function is **process.nextTick()**. I corrected the function and then i got this error message. **node.js:415
            callback();
            ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)**

Comment: As in completely outside the **io.on()** or outside the **socket.on()** but inside **io.on()**

Comment: Its not working. Still the same error. **node.js:415 callback(); ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)**

Comment: function doesnot return value however you can start a callback or set the desired value to another variable without any callback